# Datalist dropdown is shown even after selecting the value from datalist

Tags: angular, datalist

I am able to load datalist using API and select the value from the dropdown but the dropdown does not close rather it popups again with the selected value

```
 <input class="form-control"  (keyup)='getTransferFromLocations()'
  type="text" list="shiplist" [id]="shiptoid"                          
  formControlName="shiptoid">
  <datalist id="shiplist">
     <select>
      <option *ngFor="let obj of transferLocationlist" [value]="obj.facilityId"></option>
     </select>
   </datalist>
```

[image]

after selecting the value from datalist,the selected value is shown again
How to hide the same value showing twice as well as the history

Answer (score 1):

As far as the history it sounds like your wanting to hide the autocomplete. you can just add:

```
<input autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: This is not the answer